# Define Dynamic Range for a Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Background**

I find myself quiet often in the situation where I want to define a dynamic range covering a whole table. I want enough flexibility in the sense that if I add more columns or rows or move the table, the range should be updated.

So what I do is basically:

- Name the left upper cell of the table (`start.table` say)
- Define the dynamic range of the table as follows:

  ```
    =OFFSET(start.table;0;0;
            COUNTA(INDIRECT(
                   SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(start.table);1);"$1";"") & ":" & 
                   SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(start.table);1);"$1";"")));
            COUNTA(INDIRECT(
                   SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN(start.table));"$A";"") & ":" & 
                   SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN(start.table));"$A";""))))
  ```

**Explanation**

- `ADDRESS` gives me a string representation of the entire column / row of cell `start.table`
- I need to `SUBSTITUTE` the `$1` and `$A` part to get just the column or the row qualifier respectively
- Then I can `COUNTA` the non empty cells in the `INDIRECT` range as referenced by the `SUBSTITUTE` string
- With this approach the table stays properly defined even If I would add empty lines before/after the table or add columns or rows

**Question**

This approach seems to be quite on overkill and I was thinking whether I could not simply replace the whole `INDIRECT(...)` construct by `$A:$A` and `$1:$1` respectively. First test would confirm that it works, but I was wondering whether I am overlooking something here? Do you see any potenital issues with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use in name manager to define dynamic table:

```
=OFFSET(SheetName!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(SheetName!$A:$A),COUNTA(SheetName!$1:$1))
```

This will cover all the rows and columns on your given sheet.